# Error Handling when calling Go function from C++

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I am calling a Go function from C++(using [CGO](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/))

Can someone help me in best practices to handle errors when calling a Go function from C++. For example, if the Go function wishes to return error to C++ code, what would a good way to do that?

I tried doing some research but didn't find any examples or best practices with respect to it. Thanks!